# 3rd party Images gets broken in nextjs production environment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, deployment, next.js

Images that get a response from API are showing broken on production env of next.js.

[image]

Here is my code

```
import Image from 'next/image';
//import PlaceHolderImage from "../public/images/placeholder.png";

interface IProps {
    soldDate?: string;
    price: string;
    address: string;
    bed: number;
    bath: number;
    cars: number;
    sqm?: number | null;
    image: any;
}

const PropertyCardInfo = (props: IProps): JSX.Element => {  

    return (
        <div className="h-auto text-cpBlack border border-cpGreyLine mb-4">
            <div className="w-full h-auto relative">
                <Image
                    src={props.image}
                    alt={props.address}
                    width={360}
                    height={238}
                    layout="responsive"
                />
            </div>
            <div className="h-auto flex flex-col justify-between mt-1.5">
                <div className="flex items-center justify-between pt-3.5 px-3.5">
                    <p className="font-semibold">{props.price}</p>
                    {props.soldDate && <p className="text-cpGrey text-sm">Sold {props.soldDate}</p>}
                </div>
                <a href="#" className="my-2 px-3.5 text-sm hover:text-cpOrange">
                    {props.address}
                </a>
                <div className="pb-3.5 px-3.5 flex text-sm font-semibold">
                    <p className="mr-2">
                        {props.bed}
                        <span className="ml-0.5">bed</span>
                    </p>
                    <p className="mr-2">
                        {props.bath}
                        <span className="ml-0.5">bath</span>
                    </p>
                    <p className="mr-2">
                        {props.cars}
                        <span className="ml-0.5">cars</span>
                    </p>
                    {props.sqm && (
                        <p className="mr-2">
                            {props.sqm}
                            <span className="ml-0.5">sqm</span>
                        </p>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default PropertyCardInfo;
```

I have whitelisted the domain and image URL domain in the next.config.js.

It also works well in development and local build environment.

But on deployment to UAT env, it show broken link and show the below error.

[image]

But if I pass same image through custom loader function then it worked.

```
const ImgLoader = ({ src }) => {
        return props.image;
    };

    <Image
            loader={ImgLoader}
            src={props.image}
            alt={props.address}
            width={360}
            height={238}
            layout="responsive"
        />
```

Do I need to use custom loader for 3rd party images or Do I need to install `sharp` plugin ?

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: which version of next you use ?

Comment: Do you have access to UAT logs, what errors are you seeing - in another question I answered the cloud function did not allow for writing..

Comment: next version - "12.0.8" @MohsenMahoski